# Javascript error: "First argument must be a string or a buffer" with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have a template-main.js file that has a function that creates the webpage to show based on three inputs. This is what it originally said:

```
exports.build = function(title, pagetitle, content) {
  return ['<!doctype html>',
  '<html lang="en"><meta charset="utf-8"><title>{title}</title>',
  '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css" />',
  '<h1>{pagetitle}</h1>',
  '<div id="content">{content}</div>']
  .join('n')
  .replace(/{title}/g, title)
  .replace(/{pagetitle}/g, pagetitle)
  .replace(/{content}/g, content);
};
```

This method worked grat, but I wanted to move the html to a separate file, so I created template-main.html an put this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>{title}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{pagetitle}</h1>
  <div id="content">{content}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After that I changed template-main.js so that it would read the contents of the HTML file and save it as a variable:

```
var $ = require('jquery')(require("jsdom").jsdom().defaultView);

var template = $.ajax({
    url : "template-main.html",
    success : function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});

exports.build = function(title, pagetitle, content) {
  return template;
};
```

I don't want to modify the title placeholders yet, so I didn't add that bit of code, but when I start the project with, I get this error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
listening to http://127.0.0.1:8000
_http_outgoing.js:456
    throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:456:11)
    at Object.exports.get (C:\HorquetaNet\controllers\home.js:15:7)
    at Object.exports.get (C:\HorquetaNet\router.js:18:37)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\HorquetaNet\server.js:5:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Question: ¿How can I change template-main.js file so that this works?¿Is there a way to still change the text in the placeholders?

Comment: XY problem. Use a proper templating engine.

Comment: Like @Amberlamps said, use pug or some other templating engine.  This code is going to cause you all sorts of problems.

Comment: Since you're in node.js, I would strongly recommend using [node's facilities for making HTTP calls](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback), rather than using jQuery's. While jQuery can work in some situations on the server, that's not where it was meant to be used.

Comment: Thank you all, I am no longer using Node.js and now I am using the defauilt firebase template with jQuery. It's working perfectly.